Momentum on a Kinematic Character Controller Does Not Work with Jolt 3D
After a long time, I’ve finally figured out how to add momentum to my Kinematic Character Controller in Godot 4.
Before: https://youtu.be/sPl-uA7OZ0Y
After: https://youtu.be/JvywZp5sQc8
In other words, I'm now on the "How it should be" stage: https://s12.gifyu.com/images/SaHeI.gif
Here's the source: https://github.com/CryptoMares/QL-HL-Controller
I have one major issue, though—this code only works with the GodotPhysics3D engine and not with the Jolt 3D physics engine, and I don’t understand why. If anyone knows what’s going on or how to make it work with Jolt 3D, please help!
This is the full code:
extends CharacterBody3D

@export_range(0.0, 1.0, 0.001) var linear_force_multiplier = 0.045
@export_range(0.0, 1.0, 0.001) var rotation_force_multiplier = 0.015

var current_platform: Node3D = null
var previous_platform_transform: Transform3D
var is_being_pushed: bool = false

func _physics_process(delta):
    var collision = get_last_slide_collision()
    if collision:
        var collider = collision.get_collider()
        
        if collider != current_platform:
            current_platform = collider
            previous_platform_transform = current_platform.global_transform
            is_being_pushed = false
        
        if current_platform:
            var current_transform = current_platform.global_transform
            
            # Split velocity calculation into linear and rotational components
            var linear_velocity = _calculate_linear_velocity(
                previous_platform_transform.origin,
                current_transform.origin,
                delta
            )
            
            var rotational_velocity = _calculate_rotational_velocity(
                previous_platform_transform,
                current_transform,
                global_position,
                delta
            )
            
            # Apply velocities with separate multipliers
            velocity += linear_velocity * linear_force_multiplier
            velocity += rotational_velocity * rotation_force_multiplier
            
            # Update transform for next frame
            previous_platform_transform = current_transform
            
            # Report significant movement (using combined velocity for threshold check)
            var total_velocity = linear_velocity + rotational_velocity
            if total_velocity.length() > 0.1:
                if not is_being_pushed:
                    print("Started being pushed by platform")
                    is_being_pushed = true
            elif is_being_pushed:
                print("No longer being pushed")
                is_being_pushed = false
    else:
        current_platform = null
        is_being_pushed = false

func _calculate_linear_velocity(old_position: Vector3, new_position: Vector3, delta: float) -> Vector3:
    return (new_position - old_position) / delta

func _calculate_rotational_velocity(old_transform: Transform3D, new_transform: Transform3D, point: Vector3, delta: float) -> Vector3:
    # Get point's position relative to rotation center
    var local_point = old_transform.inverse() * point
    
    # Calculate position after pure rotation (excluding translation)
    var rotation_only_transform = Transform3D(new_transform.basis, old_transform.origin)
    var rotated_point = rotation_only_transform * local_point
    
    # Return rotational velocity
    return (rotated_point - point) / delta


What happens when you use this code with Jolt? What specific symptoms of "not working" do you observe?

If you compare the Before and After videos, then it turns into before — there's no momentum when pushed by the platforms. If you open the source in Godot, get Jolt 3D from the AssetLib and switch to it in the physics settings, then it should become obvious to you.
